# New Chrome Dev Tools emulation menu won't disappear

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I turned on emulation in the Chrome Dev Tools in Chrome 38 on Windows.  The new [dev tools menu](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) adds some cool inline features to the page, but I can't seem to turn them off.

I tried to turn emulation off both by unchecking all the emulated aspects and hitting <kbd>Reset</kbd>:

[image: turn off]

But the on page tools won't go away whenever I re-open the Developer Tools.

[image: dev tools]

**How can I toggle this off?**

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out while I was taking screenshots for the question.

The in page tools don't have to do with emulation persée.  They appear whenever the Developer Tools is open and the **Device Mode** has been toggled to Mobile.  This paves the way for emulation to occur, but is toggled independently.

You can turn it off by going to the top left of the dev tools screen and clicking the little phone icon:

[image: Toggle Device Mode]